# Why does my mod-mail not work, but deleting messages work in discord.py Python Programming?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm having some trouble figuring out why one part of my code works, but the other part does not. Both pieces of code work perfectly separately, however, when put in the same file, only one will work.

I'm making a Discord Bot with discord.py, one part of the code (The top part) is supposed to be mod-mail, taking a message you DM the bot and then relaying it to a channel in the server. Then a moderator, for example, can reply the person by taking their user ID and pinging them with <@userid> , then, the bot will take that message and send it to the person who DMed the bot. <-- **This part of the code doesn't work**

The 2nd part of my file basically monitors a channel called img-only and deletes any message that does not have an empty string, which means no message that isn't an image/file can be sent without being deleted. <-- **This function works, it deletes any string in the img-only channel**

Here's my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

#mod-mail
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    empty_array = []
    modmail_channnel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name = "mod-mail")
    
    if message.author == client.user:
        return 
    if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await modmail_channnel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] ")
    
            for file in files:
                await modmail_channnel.send(file.url)
        else:
            await modmail_channnel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] " + message.content)
    
    elif str(message.channel) == "mod-mail" and message.content.startswith("<"):
        member_object = message.mentions[0]
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] ")
    
            for file in files:
                await member_object.send(file.url)
        else:
            index = message.content.index(" ")
            string = message.content
            mod_message = string[index:]
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] " + mod_message)

#img-only moderation
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.channel) == "img-only" and message.content != "":
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
    

client.run('Bot Token')
```

I use Python 3.8.5, Discord.py 1.4.1, Visual Studio Code is my code editor

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you can only have one `on_message` using a `Client` instance; Since you have more than one, only the last `on_message` will be called. One way of fixing this is by combining both of your `on_message` events together into one `on_message`

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Mod-mail
    empty_array = []
    modmail_channnel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name="mod-mail")

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await modmail_channnel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] ")

            for file in files:
                await modmail_channnel.send(file.url)
        else:
            await modmail_channnel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] " + message.content)

    elif str(message.channel) == "mod-mail" and message.content.startswith("<"):
        member_object = message.mentions[0]
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] ")

            for file in files:
                await member_object.send(file.url)
        else:
            index = message.content.index(" ")
            string = message.content
            mod_message = string[index:]
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] " + mod_message)

    # img-only moderation
    if str(message.channel) == "img-only" and message.content != "":
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
```

Another way is switching to a `Bot` instance and using `listeners`. In the example below the img-only moderation is a `listener` to your main `on_message`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Mod-mail
    empty_array = []
    modmail_channnel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name="mod-mail")

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await modmail_channnel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] ")

            for file in files:
                await modmail_channnel.send(file.url)
        else:
            await modmail_channnel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] " + message.content)

    elif str(message.channel) == "mod-mail" and message.content.startswith("<"):
        member_object = message.mentions[0]
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] ")

            for file in files:
                await member_object.send(file.url)
        else:
            index = message.content.index(" ")
            string = message.content
            mod_message = string[index:]
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] " + mod_message)
    await client.process_commands(message)


# img-only moderation
@client.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.channel) == "img-only" and message.content != "":
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
```